# Button triggered repaint() not working while call the function directly works fine

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, actionlistener

I was creating an animation using recursion showing the process of Hanoi Tower.
Here is my complete code, my question is when I using main to call the `move()` function, everything works fine, but when I tried to use a button, it does not work. Console output indicating the `move()` does getting called but the window does not get refreshed. Really got stuck here, Help much appreciated.

```
public class TowerOfHanoi<T>{

//empty constructor, just for calling initializing methods
public TowerOfHanoi(){

}

private int numberOfLayers;

private Object[] towerA;
private Object[] towerB;
private Object[] towerC;

public int towerHeightOf(Object[] theTower){
    int result =0;
    for(Object current: theTower){
        if(current != null){
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


// initialize the arrays that holds the integer that represent the plate in tower
public void setLayerNbr(int layerNbr){
    this.numberOfLayers = layerNbr;
    this.moveCount = 0;

    towerA = new Object[numberOfLayers];
    towerB = new Object[numberOfLayers];
    towerC = new Object[numberOfLayers];

    //initialize the tower A
    for(int i=0; i< numberOfLayers; i++){
        towerA[i] = new Integer(layerNbr--);
    }
}

//these are the plate shifting method
//return the top most element of the tower
//warning, you are not only get the top plate, but remove it from the original racket as well
//specifications is the hardest stuff
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getTopPlate(Object[] tower){
    Object lastElement = null;
    if(tower[tower.length-1] != null){
        lastElement = tower[tower.length-1];
    }
    for(int i=tower.length-1; i>-1; i--){
        if(tower[i] != null){
            lastElement = tower[i];
            tower[i] = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (T) lastElement;
}

// add a plate to a tower
public void addToTop(T currentPlate, Object[] targetTower){
    for(int i=0; i< numberOfLayers; i++){
        if(targetTower[i] == null){
            targetTower[i] = currentPlate;
            return;
        }
    }
}

// move the top plate from one to another
public void movePlate(Object[] originalTower, Object[] targetTower){
    addToTop(getTopPlate(originalTower), targetTower);
}

public Object[] getTowerByName(char name){
    Object[] result = null;
    switch(name){
    case 'A':
        result = towerA;
        break;

    case 'B':
        result = towerB;
        break;

    case 'C':
        result = towerC;
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    return result;
}

public void showTower(char name){
    Object[] currentTower = getTowerByName(name);
    for(int i=currentTower.length-1; i>-1; i--){
        if(currentTower[i] != null){
            System.out.println(currentTower[i].toString());
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * in most scenarios, nested components plus layout manager can achieve what you want
 */

private int moveCount;

///////
///////
///////
///////



private JFrame windowFrame; // top level container

private JPanel promptPanel; // contains the following two panels
private JLabel messageLabel;
private JLabel moveCountLabel;

private JPanel animationPanel;

private JPanel bottomeStaticPanel;// contains the following two panels

private JPanel buttonPanel; // contains the following
private JButton startBtn;
private JButton pauseBtn;
private JButton quitBtn;

private JPanel racketPanel;         // contains the following 3 panels, using grid panel
private JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("A");
private JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("B");
private JLabel cLabel = new JLabel("C");



//display the static background of the window
public void display(){

    windowFrame = new JFrame("Tower of Hanoi");
    windowFrame.setSize(1200, 700);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    windowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    windowFrame.setBackground(Color.white);
    Container frameContainer = windowFrame.getContentPane();

    //set up the prompt panel
    promptPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Click \"Start\" to see the move!                          ");
    moveCountLabel = new JLabel("Moves Count: "+ moveCount+"    ");
    Font messageFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20);
    Font moveCountFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 15);
    messageLabel.setFont(messageFont);
    moveCountLabel.setFont(moveCountFont);
    messageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    moveCountLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    promptPanel.add(messageLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    promptPanel.add(moveCountLabel,BorderLayout.EAST);

    //set up the animation panel
    // todo: back ground color to be changed
    animationPanel = new JPanel();
    animationPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 700));
    animationPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    animationPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    //set up the racket panel 
    aLabel = new JLabel("Tower A");
    bLabel = new JLabel("Tower B");
    cLabel = new JLabel("Tower C");
    Font racketFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 17);
    aLabel.setFont(racketFont);
    bLabel.setFont(racketFont);
    cLabel.setFont(racketFont);
    aLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    bLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    cLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    racketPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    racketPanel.add(aLabel);
    racketPanel.add(bLabel);
    racketPanel.add(cLabel);
    racketPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    //set up the button panel
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    pauseBtn = new JButton("Pause");
    quitBtn = new JButton("Quit");


    startBtn.setEnabled(true);
    pauseBtn.setEnabled(false);
    quitBtn.setEnabled(true);

    buttonPanel.add(startBtn);
    buttonPanel.add(pauseBtn);
    buttonPanel.add(quitBtn);

    //set up the bottom panel
    bottomeStaticPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    bottomeStaticPanel.add(racketPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    bottomeStaticPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //set up the whole window frame
    frameContainer.add(promptPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frameContainer.add(animationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frameContainer.add(bottomeStaticPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //position the window frame on screen and display it
    windowFrame.setLocation(dim.width/2-windowFrame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-windowFrame.getSize().height/2);
    windowFrame.setVisible(true);

    ///*******////
    ///*******////
    ///*******////
    ///*******////
    //NOTE: since the constructor of the paintable panel needs animation panel's size, we need to make the JFrame render first
    PaintablePanel canvas = new PaintablePanel();// the panel actually do the animation

    animationPanel.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER); //make the canvas take up the entire animation panel
    //Why make this nested structure, this way we can get size of the container.

    //this is vital, you must repaint after adding something to the container?
    //Other wise the change will not show up
    windowFrame.revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setUpActionListeners(){
    startBtn.addActionListener(new startBtnListener());
    pauseBtn.addActionListener(new pauseBtnListener());
    quitBtn.addActionListener(new quitBtnListener());
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PaintablePanel extends JPanel{

    //dimension constant
    private final int HORIZONTAL_UNIT = animationPanel.getWidth()/1200; // 10 pixel per unit
    private final int PLATE_THICKNESS = animationPanel.getHeight()/(numberOfLayers+1);
    private final int BORDER_WIDTH = 2;
    private final int VERTICAL_BAR_STARTING_X = HORIZONTAL_UNIT*200-5;
    private final int BAR_HEIGHT =PLATE_THICKNESS*(numberOfLayers+1) ;
    private final int VERTICAL_BAR_STARTING_Y = animationPanel.getHeight()-BAR_HEIGHT;
    private final int PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT = 300*HORIZONTAL_UNIT/numberOfLayers;

    //color constant
    private final Color PLATE_COLOR = Color.CYAN;
    private final Color PLATE_BORDER_COLOR = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    private final Color VERTICAL_BAR_COLOR = Color.black;
    private final Color CHARACTER_COLOR = Color.blue;



    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        //todo : paint three towers according to its current status
        //paint the vertical bar;
        g.setColor(VERTICAL_BAR_COLOR);
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
            g.fillRect(VERTICAL_BAR_STARTING_X+i*400*HORIZONTAL_UNIT
                    ,VERTICAL_BAR_STARTING_Y
                    ,10
                    ,BAR_HEIGHT);
        }
        //debug
        int AHeight = towerHeightOf(towerA);
        int BHeight = towerHeightOf(towerB);
        int CHeight = towerHeightOf(towerC);



        for(int i=0; i<AHeight; i++){
            Integer currentPlate = (Integer)towerA[i];
            //NOTE: cast to double then cast back to int, make sure there is always something to display
            int outterX= (int) (200*HORIZONTAL_UNIT - ((double)currentPlate.intValue())/2*PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT);
            int outterY= animationPanel.getHeight() - PLATE_THICKNESS*(i+1); //the shifting amount of outterY relates to the layers accumulated
            int outterWidth = currentPlate.intValue()*PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT;
            int outterHeight = PLATE_THICKNESS;
            int innerX = outterX+BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerY = outterY+BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerWidth = outterWidth - 2*BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerHeight = outterHeight - 2*BORDER_WIDTH;
            int centerX = 200*HORIZONTAL_UNIT;
            int centerY = outterY+PLATE_THICKNESS/2;
            Font characterFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, PLATE_THICKNESS/4);
            g.setColor(PLATE_BORDER_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(outterX, outterY, outterWidth, outterHeight);
            g.setColor(PLATE_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(innerX, innerY, innerWidth, innerHeight);
            g.setColor(CHARACTER_COLOR);
            g.setFont(characterFont);
            g.drawString(currentPlate.toString(), centerX-characterFont.getSize()/3, centerY+characterFont.getSize()/4);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<BHeight; i++){
            Integer currentPlate = (Integer)towerB[i];
            //NOTE: cast to double then cast back to int, make sure there is always something to display
            int outterX= (int) (600*HORIZONTAL_UNIT - ((double)currentPlate.intValue())/2*PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT);
            int outterY= animationPanel.getHeight() - PLATE_THICKNESS*(i+1); //the shifting amount of outterY relates to the layers accumulated
            int outterWidth = currentPlate.intValue()*PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT;
            int outterHeight = PLATE_THICKNESS;
            int innerX = outterX+BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerY = outterY+BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerWidth = outterWidth - 2*BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerHeight = outterHeight - 2*BORDER_WIDTH;
            g.setColor(PLATE_BORDER_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(outterX, outterY, outterWidth, outterHeight);
            g.setColor(PLATE_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(innerX, innerY, innerWidth, innerHeight);
            int centerX = 600*HORIZONTAL_UNIT;
            int centerY = outterY+PLATE_THICKNESS/2;
            Font characterFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, PLATE_THICKNESS/4);
            g.setColor(CHARACTER_COLOR);
            g.setFont(characterFont);
            g.drawString(currentPlate.toString(), centerX-characterFont.getSize()/3, centerY+characterFont.getSize()/4);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<CHeight; i++){
            Integer currentPlate = (Integer)towerC[i];
            //NOTE: cast to double then cast back to int, make sure there is always something to display
            int outterX= (int) (1000*HORIZONTAL_UNIT - ((double)currentPlate.intValue())/2*PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT);
            int outterY= animationPanel.getHeight() - PLATE_THICKNESS*(i+1); //the shifting amount of outterY relates to the layers accumulated
            int outterWidth = currentPlate.intValue()*PLATE_WIDTH_UNIT;
            int outterHeight = PLATE_THICKNESS;
            int innerX = outterX+BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerY = outterY+BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerWidth = outterWidth - 2*BORDER_WIDTH;
            int innerHeight = outterHeight - 2*BORDER_WIDTH;
            g.setColor(PLATE_BORDER_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(outterX, outterY, outterWidth, outterHeight);
            g.setColor(PLATE_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(innerX, innerY, innerWidth, innerHeight);
            int centerX = 1000*HORIZONTAL_UNIT;
            int centerY = outterY+PLATE_THICKNESS/2;
            Font characterFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, PLATE_THICKNESS/4);
            g.setColor(CHARACTER_COLOR);
            g.setFont(characterFont);
            g.drawString(currentPlate.toString(), centerX-characterFont.getSize()/3, centerY+characterFont.getSize()/4);
        }

    }
}



/**
 * This method prints out the steps to achieve Hanoi Tower
 * 
 * @param numberOfPlates  how many plates are in the number
 * @param homeStack       
 * @param aimStack
 * @param mediaStack
 */
public void move(int numberOfPlates, char homeStack
        , char targetStack
        , char mediaStack ){


    if(numberOfPlates == 1){
        //debug
        //debug
        windowFrame.revalidate();
        windowFrame.repaint();
        System.out.println("repaint() get called");


        System.out.println("Move "+ numberOfPlates+" from Stack \'"+ homeStack+"\' to "+"Stack \'"+targetStack+"\'");
        //Truly needed
        messageLabel.setText("Move "+ numberOfPlates+" from Stack \'"+ homeStack+"\' to "+"Stack \'"+targetStack+"\'");
        movePlate(getTowerByName(homeStack), getTowerByName(targetStack));
        moveCount++;
        moveCountLabel.setText("Moves Count: "+ moveCount+"         ");

        //delay the move step for one second
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }


    move(numberOfPlates-1, homeStack, mediaStack, targetStack);


    //debug
    windowFrame.revalidate();
    windowFrame.repaint();

    System.out.println("Move "+ numberOfPlates+" from Stack \'"+ homeStack+"\' to "+"Stack \'"+targetStack+"\'");
    //debug
    messageLabel.setText("Move "+ numberOfPlates+" from Stack \'"+ homeStack+"\' to "+"Stack \'"+targetStack+"\'");
    movePlate(getTowerByName(homeStack), getTowerByName(targetStack));

    moveCount++;
    moveCountLabel.setText("Moves Count: "+ moveCount+"         ");

    //delay the move step
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    move(numberOfPlates-1, mediaStack, targetStack, homeStack);
}


class startBtnListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startBtn.setEnabled(false);
        pauseBtn.setEnabled(true);
        quitBtn.setEnabled(true);

        windowFrame.revalidate();
        windowFrame.repaint();

        System.out.println("move started");
        move(numberOfLayers, 'A', 'C', 'B');
        System.out.println("move finished");
    }

}

// to be fixed
class pauseBtnListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String status = "";
        if(pauseBtn.getText() == "Pause"){
            pauseBtn.setText("Resume");
            status = "Resume";
        }else{
            pauseBtn.setText("Pause");
        }

        //hang up the current thread
        while(status != "Resume"){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

class quitBtnListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userChoseQuit();
    }

}




////////////////
////////////////
////////////////


//check if the input string represent a valid integer
public boolean isAValidInteger(String rawInput) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(rawInput);// throw exception if rawInput is not
        // integer
        return true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input must be an integer",
                "Invalid input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
}

// This method show a message if the user click cancel during the execution
// of the program
// and terminate the program
public void userChoseQuit() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Program terminated by user before finish execution.",
            "Program exit successfully, good bye! ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);
}

//recursively validating the input
public int getInput(){
    String userInputLayersNbr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please Enter the Number Of Layers of Hanoi Tower:",
            "Wecome To Tower Of Hanoi Animation", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if(userInputLayersNbr == null){
        this.userChoseQuit();
        return -1;
    }else{
        if(this.isAValidInteger(userInputLayersNbr)){
            int layerNbr = Integer.parseInt(userInputLayersNbr);
            if(layerNbr >= 1){
                return layerNbr;
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Number of layers must be an integer greater than 0",
                        "Try Again Please", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                return this.getInput();
            }
        }
        return this.getInput();
    }

}

/////////////////
/////////////////
/////////////////



public static void main(String[] args){


    TowerOfHanoi<Integer> theTower = new TowerOfHanoi<>();
    int layerNbr =theTower.getInput();
    theTower.setLayerNbr(layerNbr);

    theTower.display();
    theTower.setUpActionListeners();
    //let us use the button to call move now
    //theTower.move(layerNbr, 'A', 'C', 'B');

    return;

}
```

}

Comment: Let's start with, don't override `paint` of `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method instead and make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting. Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: My guess would be you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing the U from been updated until the movement process has completed.  Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for possible solutions

Answer (score 2):

> when I using main to call the move() function, everything works

Code invoked from your main() method is running on a separate Thread (which is wrong by the way since all GUI code should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

> when I tried to use a button, it does not work

Code executing in a listener is invoked on the EDT which is the Thread responsible for repainting the GUI. Since you have a Thread.sleep(), this will cause the EDT to sleep, which means the GUI can't repaint itself.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on this concept.

The solution is to use a separate Thread for the long running task, then when you cause the Thread to sleep it won't affect the GUI.

Or maybe you use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation, so you don't need to use Thread.sleep. In any case the code needs to be restructured. Read the tutorial. The tutorial also has a section on Timers.

Also, you should NOT be overriding the paint() method. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a panel and don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent() to clear the background.

Comment: Thank you very much! Honestly I have no idea what exactly thread is. Just try to play around with the newly learnt GUI stuff and some algorithms. I should not copy and paste the `Thread.sleep()` stuff before understanding it. I am catching up with my readings.